# EBS Volume from Ubuntu to RedHat

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, redhat

I would like to use an EBS volume with data on it that I've been working with in an Ubuntu AMI in a RedHat 6 AMI. The issue I'm having is that RedHat says that the volume does not have a valid partition table. This is the fdisk output for the unmounted volume.

Disk /dev/xvdk: 901.9 GB, 901875499008 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 109646 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/xvdk doesn't contain a valid partition table

Interestingly, the volume isn't actually 901.9 GB but 300 GB.. I don't know if that means anything. I am very concerned about possibly erasing the data in the volume by accident. Can anyone give me some pointers for formatting the volume for RedHat without deleting its contents?

I also just checked that the volume works in my Ubuntu instance and it definitely does.

Comment: Which file system is currently in use on the EBS volume?

Comment: The file system is ext2, which is why I don't understand why it's having a hard time. Isn't that one of the most basic types? I will take your advice and snapshot the volume. Thanks for that tip.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to advise on the partition issue as such, other than stating that you definitely neither need nor want to format it, because formatting is indeed a (potentially) destructive operation. My best guess would be that RedHat isn't able to identify the file system currently in use on the EBS volume, which must be advertized by some means accordingly.

However, to ease with experimenting and gain some peace of mind, you should get acquainted with one of the major [Amazon EBS](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) features, namely to *create point-in-time snapshots of volumes, which are persisted to Amazon S3*:

> These snapshots can be used as the starting point for new Amazon EBS
>   volumes, and protect data for long-term durability. The same snapshot
>   can be used to instantiate as many volumes as you wish.

This is detailed further down in section *Amazon EBS Snapshots*:

> Snapshots can also be used to **instantiate multiple new volumes**, expand
>   the size of a volume or move volumes across Availability Zones. When a
>   new volume is created, there is the option to create it based on an
>   existing Amazon S3 snapshot. In that scenario, **the new volume begins
>   as an exact replica of the original volume**. [...] *[emphasis mine]*

Therefore you can (and actually should) always start experiments or configuration changes like the one you are about to perform by at least snapshotting the volume (which will allow you to create a new one from that point in time in case things go bad) or creating a new volume from that snapshot immediately for the specific task at hand.

You can create snapshots and new volumes from snapshots via the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/), as usual there are respective APIs available as well for automation purposes (see [API and Command Overview](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-api-cli-overview.html)) - see [Creating an Amazon EBS Snapshot](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html) for details.

Good luck!.